# Moshi: Why no need to register generated JsonAdapters?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I'm using [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) and its CodeGen to generate Kotlin JsonAdaptors automatically for Retrofit's ConvertorFactory.

I add `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` on top of my data classes and after make project all adapters will be available. Then I define `MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi)` in retrofit builder like this:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl(/* baseUrl */)
     .client(/* okHttpClient */)
     .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
     .addCallAdapterFactory(/* ... */)
     .build()
```

My question is: **How Moshi will find the generated adapters?**

As you can see, there's not required to register them as custom JsonAdapters for Moshi. They work well. (I checked them in debug mode and their function will be invoked)

It's my pleasure if you refer me to its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moshi uses naming conventions to find the generated adapters. It attempts to find those classes in the expected location, and if they're found then they're used.